# lsFusion, how JSONFILE can be saved to the TEXT property?

Tags: open-source, lsfusion

Good afternoon everyone, has anyone had any experience with how `JSONFILE` can be saved to the `TEXT` property in lsFusion?

I couldn't find the right function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

yes, you can

```
INPUT f = JSONFILE DO { 
          LOCAL text = TEXT();
          text() <- TEXT(f);
          MESSAGE text();
 }
```